# Symbol error with GCC-4.4.2 libstdc++.so.6 library

Tags: linux

I am building GCC-4.4.2 ( open embedded recipe using bitbake version-1.8 ) for an x86 based system.

The configure options are as under:

```
"--enable-libssp --disable-bootstrap --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap"
```

It builds successfully after some minor changes and libstdc++.so.6.0.13 library is getting created.

My aim is to run Citrix receiver on an x86 based target. For this, I run storebrowse as follows:

```
./usr/lib/ICAClient/storebrowse
```

But I get the following errors.

```
./storebrowse: /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by ./storebrowse)
./storebrowse: relocation error: ./storebrowse: symbol _ZTISt15basic_streambufIwSt11char_traitsIwEE, version GLIBCXX_3.4 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference.
```

libxml2 error can be resolved by deleting and creating a new symbolic link to libxml. I am unable to resolve the symbol error `(_ZTISt15basic_streambufIwSt11char_traitsIwEE)`. I am compiling using default gcc_4.4.2.bb recipe.

Do I need to make any changes in configure options..?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your executable is loading the system's (older) libstdc++.  To fix this, either configure GCC with `--enable-rpath` or explicitly add RPATH to your call to g++ with `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/your/gcc/lib`, or run your executable like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/gcc/lib ./usr/lib/ICAClient/storebrowse
```

I wrote those three possible solutions in order of my personal preference.  :)

This page may be of some interest: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html